Typescript help needed with getting JSON data
I am new with typescript and developing and was wondering if you could help me.
I have a simple piece of code to fetch data from a website which "works" the only problem is to get the actual data under object data.token.
this is the site: https://gmgn.ai/defi/quotation/v1/tokens/sol/EV1k3kQwueeD3uYr3wMzeydYc94qqrpjfHdCNVs2A22d
How can I change the code to get only the JSON response (at the end of this response example) data.token.symbol and Name?
The code returns this:
const axios = require('axios')

axios.get('https://gmgn.ai/defi/quotation/v1/tokens/sol/EV1k3kQwueeD3uYr3wMzeydYc94qqrpjfHdCNVs2A22d')
    .then(res => {console.log(res)     
        
    })

{
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
    date: 'Thu, 27 Jun 2024 14:11:30 GMT',
    'x-powered-by': 'Express',
    etag: 'W/"bd4-nznvf3ajmxpg+hguX8CIbl0VXdQ"',
    'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': '36',
    server: 'istio-envoy',
    'x-cache': 'Miss from cloudfront',
    via: '1.1 459ec09472abb8544521a9b5cc6706ce.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
    'x-amz-cf-pop': 'AMS58-P5',
    'x-amz-cf-id': 'h1W08tqCuJTIf8fsKFjnWRoYvkYzSSND3ZCH36AzgQax8msy3Mj6Jw==',
    'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
    'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'referrer-policy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
    'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000'
  },
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http', 'fetch' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': undefined,
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.7.2',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://gmgn.ai/defi/quotation/v1/tokens/sol/EV1k3kQwueeD3uYr3wMzeydYc94qqrpjfHdCNVs2A22d',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: true,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'gmgn.ai',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'gmgn.ai',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: null,
      autoSelectFamilyAttemptedAddresses: [Array],
      [Symbol(alpncallback)]: null,
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: -1,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 5000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 378,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 26,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 24
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 1,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'GET /defi/quotation/v1/tokens/sol/EV1k3kQwueeD3uYr3wMzeydYc94qqrpjfHdCNVs2A22d HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/1.7.2\r\n' +
      'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
      'Host: gmgn.ai\r\n' +
      'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype],
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: true,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
    path: '/defi/quotation/v1/tokens/sol/EV1k3kQwueeD3uYr3wMzeydYc94qqrpjfHdCNVs2A22d',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _events: [Object],
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: null,
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 200,
      statusMessage: 'OK',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: true,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      responseUrl: 'https://gmgn.ai/defi/quotation/v1/tokens/sol/EV1k3kQwueeD3uYr3wMzeydYc94qqrpjfHdCNVs2A22d',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 38,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'gmgn.ai',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _events: [Object],
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://gmgn.ai/defi/quotation/v1/tokens/sol/EV1k3kQwueeD3uYr3wMzeydYc94qqrpjfHdCNVs2A22d',
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'accept-encoding': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
    [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  data: {
    code: 0,
    msg: 'success',
  **  data: { token: [Object], **vote: [Object], my_vote: [Object] }
  }
}

I couldn't get pass this problem unfortunately

What about accessing the data property by its name, ie console.log(res.data)?

const axios = require('axios')

axios.get('https://gmgn.ai/defi/quotation/v1/tokens/sol/EV1k3kQwueeD3uYr3wMzeydYc94qqrpjfHdCNVs2A22d')
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)  
    });


thank you! this helped a lot but how can I only select Token name from the data set?

to get whatever data you want out of the response you just have to index into it and get what you want. Since you're new to programming it can seem a bit difficult but in javascript its probably one of the simplest, and in general indexing into different data structures is not too hard.
Basically when dealing with json and javascript, its quite easy and they work very well together since json stands for JavaScript Object Notation. And basically the only types of variables are primitives (number, string, boolean) and then I guess compound types that are either objects or arrays. I think this is mostly right, it's a basic explanation but I think it's got whats most useful.
So what we care about for this example is mainly the objects and arrays.
You can index into objects using the key of the object. So if you have
const data = { a: "hi" };

then
data.a // or data["a"]

will return "hi"
And for multiple indices
const data = { aa: {b: "hello" } };


data.aa.b //or data["aa"]["b"]

will return "hello"
For arrays its very similar, in reality arrays are mostly just objects with number keys, but to index them you use [<index>]. So given data
const data = ["a","b","c","d"]

For indices 0 and 2 for example, you get the following
data[0] // "a"
data[2] // "c"

So in your case, you're more interested in objects since the response is all objects. Following this, from the return on https://gmgn.ai/defi/quotation/v1/tokens/sol/EV1k3kQwueeD3uYr3wMzeydYc94qqrpjfHdCNVs2A22d
Doing
{
  const token = res.data.token;
  const name = res.data.token.name;
  //or just const name = token.name since you already have token
}

Should work.
More generally, I think axios already returns parsed JSON so you do not have to call JSON.parse on the response. Using fetch for example you may have to call await res.json().
So once you have the object, you just have to index into the variables you want.
As for typescript, since the data is coming from outside the app, there is no information on the types so the return type from res.json() is any which in typescript just means assignable to anything. You can specify the type if you have one, or even just parts of it. A lazy way to do it is to paste the response into some environment and look at the type, for example hovering over the response from the url, we get.
const res: {
    code: number;
    msg: string;
    data: {
        token: {
            symbol: string;
            name: string;
            decimals: number;
            price: number;
            logo: string;
            price_1m: number;
            price_5m: number;
            price_1h: number;
            price_6h: number;
            price_24h: number;
            ... 77 more ...;
            dev_token_burn_ratio: null;
        };
        vote: {
            ...;
        };
        my_vote: {
            ...;
        };
    };
}

and you can assign in your code somewhere like
type T = typeof res

assuming the variable with your pasted response is called res and you want to call your type T
then you just do
const data:T = res;

or
(res as T) 

wherever you want to the type.
If you just want some to type some of the object because its all you need, you can also just write the type yourself, for example
type Data = {data:{token:{name:string}}};

and then assign that type to the variable, this works because typescript allows excess properties which means the object must have at least the properties defined in the type in order for it to be considered assignable to that type, but it could have extra properties.
But depending on your case you probably want to get somewhat of a comprehensive type so you know what you're dealing with, but its not essential, and also at that point if just processing some response you can leave the type as any, it's up to you to see how much typescript you want to use and where.
But one more thing that's important to consider is conditional access, for example if you don't know the response will necessarily have all the properties in the object, you can use ?. instead of . to access properties of objects when the object may be undefined. This is only really relevant for nested objects where the indexed object itself may at some point be undefined.
Either way, this answer may be a bit longer than it needed to be but I think its important to actually understand some of these concepts if you want to enjoy working on whatever you're working on, heres a typescript playground link just as context for some of these concepts discussed.
